# How to add text into div in wordpress theme front-page.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to write text into a div in PHP. This is in a Wordpress theme that is not so easy to customize and I am new to PHP.

Ultimately, I would like to include text in .products

```
{
echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8">';
            echo '<h2 class="products">'.We.'</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

I have tried this but I get a parse error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'blah' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/fdwildfoods.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/shop-isle-child/front-page.php on line 125
```

Attempted code

```
{
echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8">';
            echo '<h2 class="products">'.We blah blah blah.'</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: instead    echo '<h2 class="products">'.We blah blah blah.'</h2>'; use     echo '<h2 class="products">'. 'We blah blah blah' .'</h2>'; it is syntax error you did not wrap string in quotes     echo '<h2 class="products">'.We.'</h2>'; should be     echo '<h2 class="products">'. 'We' .'</h2>';

Comment: have solved with this code '{
echo '<div class="container">';
 echo '<div class="row">';
  echo '<div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8">';
   echo '<h2 class="products">
   <p>Fusce neque dolor adipiscing sed consectetuer et lacinia sit amet quam. Suspendisse wisi quam consectetuer in blandit sed suscipit eu eros.</p>
   </h2>';
  echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}'

Comment: ok thank you for the solution and explanation

Comment: I hate seeing a ton of `echos` when all you need is 1 and use concatenation (either `,` or `.`).

Answer (score 0):

instead echo ''.We blah blah blah.''; use echo ''. 'We blah blah blah' .''; it is syntax error you did not wrap string in quotes echo ''.We.''; should be echo ''. 'We' .'';

Answer (score 0):

Since it's wordpress, you should put the text in a variable without having to escape strings in one single line especially if you have complex text with apostrophes and etc.

```
<?php
$text = "Products text goes here";

echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8">';
            echo '<h2 class="products">'; echo $text; echo '</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```